# Difference between "a//b" and "int(a/b)"

Tags: python, casting, floor-division

I know `a/b` is floating point division and `a//b` is floor division in Python.
 It's seen that `int(a/b)` also results the same as floor division if both numerators and denominators are positive number. But on trying `-a//b` and `int(-a/b)` yield different results. What are the internal operations?

```
>>> int(-5/3)
-1
>>> -5//3
-2
```

**How different is `int(a/b)` from the equivalent floor division i.e, `a//b`?**

Comment: `floats` are rounded towards zero by default, so `int(-5/3)` ~ `int(-1.66)` ~ `-1`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I _think_ this is not an exact duplicate question, but the answer to the duplicate answers this one too.

Comment: @Selcuk the first answer addresses everything asked here i'd say? if you disagree i will reopen the question.

Comment: So `int(a/b)` rounds towards zero whereas `a//b` lowers the value obtained? Anyways the issue mentioned here wasn't asked there exactly.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist As I mentioned in my comment, I agree that the _answer_ is sufficient even though the questions are not exactly the same. No objections to leaving it as it is.

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi You are right, `int` truncates the decimal portion, so you can say that it rounds towards zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `int` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.

From `//` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> Division of integers yields a float, while floor division of integers results in an integer; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.